# How to get all options of more than one select using select name with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have multiple selects on page with name="categories" and i want to get all the options text from multiple drop down lists and want to store in array.
I google but most of the example comes with jquery and Id based.

Comment: Provide what you have tried.

Comment: Start with `$('select[name="categories"] option").map(.....)`

Comment: i got this example which is closer to my solution but again it is Id based. http://jsfiddle.net/Mer38/

Comment: It's well-worth your time to read through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour, two tops, and you learn all kinds of things, including how to select elements in ways other than by ID. Separately, I hear there may be the odd jQuery book or tutorial out there.

Comment: Thanks Satpal should i try with $(this).val() while iteration.

Comment: Oh, nice. How about you don't waste our time with questions that are already answered, both here on site and elsewhere?

Comment: (If you want someone to be notified of your comment, use @ in front of their name.) I suggest doing your own research.

Comment: Some downvoters are enjoying downvoting without reason. @MohsinAli try answer provided to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, provide a `name` to select and try to access it as follows,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var optionValues = [];

  $('select[name=sameSelect] option').each(function() {
    optionValues.push($(this).text());
  });

  $('#result').html(optionValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="state" name="sameSelect">
  <option value="state1">state1</option>
  <option value="state2">state2</option>
  <option value="state3">state3</option>
</select>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: I think down-voter down voted it without a valid reason, otherwise he should leave at least one comment for the reason. DownVotes are for wrong answers, if  it is not a best answer(but right answer) we should  not downVote it.

Comment: @ScanQR after careful consideration I found a possible reason of the down-vote. The asker asked for texts and you filled your array with values. optionValues.push($(this).text()); would certainly improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad thanks to point it out. However, it would have been a suggestion to improve as the solution is not invalid. SO asked how to get texts based on name that was main point that was addressed in this. However thanks. I have updated it.

Comment: @ScanQR you are welcome. I can no longer upvote this answer, but I appreciate its improvement.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @MohsinAli glad to help. Please accept if found useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code below initializes an empty array, gets all items matching a selector and then iterates them and pushes their inner text into the array.

```
var selector = 'select[name="categories"] option';
var optionsText = [];
var context = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
for (var index in context) {
    optionsText.push(context[index].innerText);
}
//Do something with optionsText
```

Comment: @MohsinAli you are welcome. You have two correct answers at your disposal, you could choose any of those as the correct answer. I believe you should choose one, since in that case you are helping people in the future having similar problems.